# How to remember RadzenGrid width after change the page?

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor, radzen

In my project, I'm using Radzen Components for Blazor.
To RadzenGrid I applied `AllowColumnResize="true"` property to be able to resize column with my mouse.

Is there any way to apply the column width that I applied using `AllowColumnResize="true"` everywhere in my grid?

The other problem is that - After I change the column width and navigate to second page for example and back to the first page - column width is default. Is there a method to memorize this?

My grid code:

````
                            AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowColumnResize="true" Data="@Data" TItem="ArticleVariantListModel"
                            RowSelect="@SelectRow">
                    <Columns>
                        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ArticleVariantListModel" Property="Id" Title="Id" Width="70px" />
                        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ArticleVariantListModel" Property="Name" Title="@Language.Name" Width="auto" />
                        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ArticleVariantListModel" Property="Index" Title="@Language.Index" Width="auto" />
                        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ArticleVariantListModel" Property="Barcode" Title="@Language.Barcode" />
                        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ArticleVariantListModel" Property="ArticleCategory" Title="@Language.Category" />
                        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ArticleVariantListModel" Property="Description" Title="@Language.Description" />
                        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ArticleVariantListModel" Property="Variant" Title="@Language.Variant" />
                        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ArticleVariantListModel" Property="Size" Title="@Language.Size" />
                        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="ArticleVariantListModel" Property="Price" Context="data" Title="@Language.Price">```
````

Answer (score 0):

check [this answer](https://forum.radzen.com/t/new-radzendatagrid-state-management/7967/2) for your second question. according to that answer you have to handle the grid state on your code.

Answer (score 0):

First question , yes you can set a property to all columns in your datagrid, just specify the property in the grid tag :

```
<RadzenDataGrid @Data TItem="Object" AllowColumnResize=true>
```

Second question not in radzen you should create something to sore width value(cookie, persist in bd,di etc...), then bind column width with your object

```
<RadzenDataGrid Data=data TItem=string AllowColumnResize=true ColumnWidth="fixColumnWidth">
<RadzenDataGridColumn="SomeData" TItem="Object" ColumnWidth=@width>
   </Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>
@code
{
int width:
int fixColumnWidth= 25;
protected override OnInitiallized(){
width= //(where you stored the value)
}

}
```

If you want to have the same value, you should set the value to the property ,so next time you access the component you can recover the value.